# How to kick somebody from an RDP session

Tags: rdp, windows

I am trying to RDP into a machine, but it has exceeded its maximum number of users. How do I go about kicking one of them (assuming I have admin rights).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `mstsc -V server /f -console` (where server is the hostname) to get a console session. Then you can boot people using Task Manager.

Comment: You always can connect to the console/admin session using the `/console` or `/admin` switch depending on the version of Windows Server and MS RDP client. Whoever has been connected to the console session will be disconnected, the local session will be locked.